# newline character hqlhibernate) gives error

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I building a hibernate query which needs have a newline character in it.
It give unrecognized token.

How to use newline characters in hql.

Comment: can you paste the query here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a newline `\n` character which can be stored in the db and used in a hibernate query.

`Query query = session.createQuery("from Table where column = :column_name");
query.setParameter("column_name", "...\n...");`